# PHP remove specific parent array from specific value recursive

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

Here's a multimensional array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 2
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
        )

)
```

I'm looking for a PHP function which could remove a parent or grand-parent array from a given "id" value. For example, if id == 2, I'd like to remove the closest array with the key named "children", something like that :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
        )

)
```

If id == 5, the new array would be :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
        )

)
```

Or if id == 6, the new array would be :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 2
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

  )
```

How do i do this with maybe a recursive function ? I would really appreciate some help ! Thanks ! :)

Comment: So, what have you tried? The task looks pretty basic to do via recursion.

Comment: Hello, I tried via recursion, but only "id" key is removed, not the array "parent" when it contains the "children" key

Comment: @Fabien You cannot delete children if they are also parents

Comment: I wanted to say : the array whose key is called "children" (cf the examples above)